# Magento: Different payment gateway for different store

Tags: php, magento

Can we have multiple payment gateway for multiple store? We want to create multiple store which have store dependent payment gateway like

- if user goes to usa store than he/she will checkout using
  authorize.net.
- if user goes to uk store than he/she will checkout using
  braintree or some other gateway.

I did not write any code to handle it but want to check that is there any possibilities.

Comment: I haven't personally used Magento (yet), but I will say that "yes, *every* store-software package is designed to support multiple payment gateways."  There will be some more-abstract software layer, which is intended to be gateway-independent, as well as a gateway-type-specific interface to handle the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `System > Configuration > Payment Methods`, you can see that most of payment methods have the "Active" setting on a `Website Scope`.

That means that your best solution call here would be to create a different `Website` (in Magento, a website contains store, and stores contains store views), and change the "Active" settings for the relevant websites that you create.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be handle by store scope configuration.

When you are logged in the backend go to: **System Configuration**.

Under the menu on the left you have a little box that it's called Configuration Scope and configuration is loaded:

- Default
- Website Configuration
- Store - you cannot pick it
- Store View

Pick first website from the dropdown, go to Sales -> Payment Methods -> and Save.
After that you need to pick second website and simply enable / disable payment methods you want to use.

That's all